# Is it allowed to use MuiThemeProvider for a component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have a component `View`:

```
import React from 'react';
import { AppBar, Toolbar } from 'material-ui';
import { Typography } from 'material-ui';
import { MuiThemeProvider, createMuiTheme } from 'material-ui/styles';
import {lightBlue} from 'material-ui/colors';

const theme = createMuiTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: {main:lightBlue['A700']}
  },
});

const View = (props) => (
  <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
    <AppBar position="static">
      <Toolbar>
      <Typography variant="title">
        {props.title}
      </Typography>          
      </Toolbar>
    </AppBar>
  </MuiThemeProvider>
);
export default View;
```

As you can see, the component is using own `MuiThemeProvider`. The View component is not a root component of the whole app, it is a child component of the `App` root component and the `App` component contains multiple components.

My question, it is wrong to assign `MuiThemeProvider` to not root component like `View`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://material-ui-next.com/customization/themes/#nesting-the-theme), you can nest `MuiThemeProvider` as you want.